# Why does spotlight search system files?

Tags: spotlight

Most of my spotlight search results are files in ~/Library (application data) and /usr/include (header files)

I already tried to rebuild the index.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove directories from the Spotlight Index under the Privacy tab in System Preferences > Spotlight

([Described in this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/how-can-i-make-spotlight-ignore-certain-file-types-and-directories?rq=1))