# Folder in external SSD not found by Finder Search even though it exists

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

I have two folders in an external SSD with the name "sumatera": "REGION SUMATERA" and "REGION SUMATERA 500". However, when I search for it with the Finder's Search feature, only "REGION SUMATERA" appears, the other folder "REGION SUMATERA 500" doesn't appear. Why does this happen and how do I fix Finder Search?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is the format of the external SSD (APFS, HFS+, exFAT...)? When you open the disk in the Finder, do you see both folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight excludes many types of files as well as [many portions of the drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123245/why-does-spotlight-search-system-files) from results. First step, rebuild the index for that drive and validate its format is Apple specific as spotlight only indexes HFS and APFS file systems.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

You can use finder to include “System Files” in advanced searches, but past that I would recommend a tool like `locate` or a graphical file search tool.

- https://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/
- https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/
- [Using locate on external drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48651/8888)

Once you’ve located the file, you can validate if it should be indexed and there’s a crash or data error with spotlight or it’s just excluded by design or your [Mac has custom exclusions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173488/5472).