# How to exclude certain particular files from Spotlight?

Tags: finder, spotlight

I know that you can exclude entire directories or files with a particular extension from Spotlight. But can I hand-pick files not to be searchable by Spotlight, preferably with a file system flag? I am a writer and keep old copies of my drafts but they muck up Spotlight with lots of search results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make spotlight ignore certain file types and directories?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/how-can-i-make-spotlight-ignore-certain-file-types-and-directories)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The question here is about specific files, *not* file types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.noindex](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-hide-files-and-folders-from-spotlight-search--mac-54256)

> One of the fastest ways to hide a file or folder, from Spotlight, on
>   the fly is to add the .noindex extension to the end of the filename or
>   folder. The simplest way to get those files hidden is to create a
>   folder, preferably named something innocuous, and add the extension to
>   the end of the name. I’ll end up with a folder named “Nothing to See
>   Here.noindex” or something similar.

Hide just a single file

[image: hide]

> Select the file to be hidden. Right-click and select Get Info, or
>   click Command+I. Find the Name & Extension field, and replace the
>   current extension with .noindex. When prompted to confirm that I want
>   to change the extension, I agree. Now my file is properly hidden from
>   Spotlight search.

Finlay:

Finder won’t know what to do with my file anymore, though. Look to the drop-down labeled Open With, and select an application to handle the file. Be careful of setting a single application to handle all .noindex files, as many different file types may be hidden from Spotlight, and OS X sometimes creates .noindex files itself

Comment: Won't this make it so that files won't be able to be opened in their original program?

Comment: Finder won’t know what to do with my file anymore, though. Look to the drop-down labeled Open With, and select an application to handle the file. Be careful of setting a single application to handle all .noindex files, as many different file types may be hidden from Spotlight, and OS X sometimes creates .noindex files itself.