# To exclude bak files in Finder's search?

Tags: backup, perl

I create bak files after every Perl operation.

How can you exclude all bak files in your Finder's search?

Comment: can you persuade it to save the bak files as file.bak.noindex ? If so, that will prevent Spotlight indexing them

Comment: You could retrospectively add .noindex using this applescript - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/applescript-to-automatically-add-noindex-extension-to-a-file - or even set up Automator to do it.

Comment: I didn't know my script would spread this fast :).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is to add **.noindex** -extension at the end of .bak. Thank you, Tetsujin!
I refer this one [liner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/148786/15504) to do it

```
find . -name "*\.tex" -exec bash -c 'mv "{}" "{}.noindex"' \;
```