# Exclude certain files from finder search results

Tags: finder, search

I have a bunch of massive xml files with the extension .nml that appear every time I search for anything in the finder and crowd out the files I'm actually searching for.[image]

I need a way of making the finder ignore these files when searching or some other means of searching my files that leaves out these .nml files.

Unfortunately, I am unable to [add .noindex to the end of them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/148766/83869) and for some reason when I [save a search that excludes them](https://superuser.com/a/1739636/35492) the search results leave out files I know to be on my computer.

While I would prefer to continue using the finder to search my files, I am open to any solution including third party software.

Comment: Are these file in one or two locations or all over the filesystem? If the former you can add those locations to Spotlight Privacy in System Settings. And when you search in Finder there is options that let you include and exclude certain strings in the filename. Have you tried that?

Comment: @SteveChambers thank you! I research what you suggested and it turns out the files do only reside in small handful folders which I was able to add to Spotlight Privacy. If you provide that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: To whoever closed this question, please understand the nuance here. This is not a duplicate. I already addressed 3 other questions, including the [Preventing Spotlight from Indexing Files & Folders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92784/preventing-spotlight-from-indexing-files-folders) and explained why they are different from mine. It's over-moderation like this that is making this site less useful. @SteveChambers provided a solution that is not mentioned in any of them and it helped me resolve my issue.