# Could my spotlight search index have really been 2.5 GB on a 256 GB drive?

Tags: spotlight, indexing, mds

I have a MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) with El Capitan 10.11.6 and a 256 GB SSHD. I was having fan/CPU usage issues with `mds` and using the lines in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144494/143729) turned it off and deleted the index.

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off

sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-V100/*
```

It's quiet now, and cool as a cucumber. But I was surprised to see 2.5 GB of hard drive space freed up *at the moment I deleted the index*.

My 256 GB drive is fairly full, so that's about 1%. Does that sound right? About 1% of the size of my stuff is used for indexing? Just curious.

I have quite a mix of file types, years of photos, lots of text and pdf's for research, youtube downloads, python's numpy and other text and non-text data files... does it all somehow get indexed?

Is there some magic way to stop it from opening file types I'm not interested in indexing?

---

This is the "before" situation. All is quiet now that indexing is turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you write sounds perfectly normal to me.

> > does it all somehow get indexed?

Yes it does.

> > Is there some magic way to stop it from opening file types I'm not interested in indexing?

Well, not directly. But you can exclude folders, by either adding `.noindex` to the folder name, or by going into **System Preferences** → **Spotlight** → **Privacy**. You may want to move all the files you don’t want indexed into such a location.

Also see [How can I make spotlight ignore certain file types and directories?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/how-can-i-make-spotlight-ignore-certain-file-types-and-directories) As far as I know there’s no way to tell Spotlight NOT to index certain file types.

Comment: Thanks! Of course it probably wouldn't take more than a few minutes to *reduce* my drive usage by 1%, probably less time than it took for asking and answering this question. But I feel better knowing that the index can indeed be GB's in size.