# I can no longer see the url from where I have downloaded a file in Get Info, can I get that back?

Tags: folders, data-transfer, metadata, url, indexing

I always used to use Get Info to see the URL where I've downloaded a file. Image, PDF, data. Now I can't see this field anymore in any of my recent downloads. I don't see it for old files or new.

**update:** based on the comment, I went back and looked more carefully. In the Title and Headline lines I only see the file name and extension repeated in each place.

Did I loose this information [when I deleted the indexing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/278847/143729)? Or is the display just turned off temporarily?

MacBook Air 10.11.6 El Capitan  Downloads with Chrome primarily, seems to be same with Safari downloads.

**edit:** following instructions from @user3439894's [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282269/#comment355507_282269) to drag the file into a command window after typing `xattr -1`, I can see that the url is still available somewhere, and in at least this case is correct (I've changed some codes to `xxxxxx`):

```
david-selfs-MacBook-Air:~ david$ xattr -l /Users/david/Desktop/IgRb0.png
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A2 01 02 5F 10 23 68 74  |bplist00..._.#ht|
00000010  74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 69 2E 73 74 61 63 6B 2E 69 6D  |tps://i.stack.im|
00000020  67 75 72 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 49 67 52 62 30 2E 70 6E  |gur.com/IgRb0.pn|
00000030  67 5F 10 23 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 69 2E 73 74  |g_.#https://i.st|
00000040  61 63 6B 2E 69 6D 67 75 72 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 49 67  |ack.imgur.com/Ig|
00000050  52 62 30 2E 70 6E 67 08 0B 31 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Rb0.png..1......|
00000060  01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 57                    |.........W|
0000007a
com.apple.quarantine: 0001;xxxxxxx;Google Chrome;xxxxxx—xxxxxx-…
```

[image]

Comment: When you do the Get Info (⌘+I) and the window appears, do you still see the More Info field?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yep, usually it contains `Title`, `Headline` and `Last opened` fields, and the first two now contain only a repeat of the file name, with no local path or original url information. Something like name.pdf, name.dat, or name.png. I've added a screenshot as an example, but spot checks show the same each time, except occasionally one of the subfields is missing (e.g. Headline). Also, I use the Chrome browser, a quick check in Safari shows same behavior.

Comment: In Terminal, type the following command, followed by a space, `xattr -l ` and then drag & drop the image onto the Terminal window. This populates the fully qualified pathname of the file. Now press `enter`. What output do you see? Do you see a `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms:` output?

Comment: @user3439894 It seems the correct url is displayed there (see update). I wonder if this means that I can find a way to get "show info" to start showing the links again?

Comment: I'd start by rebuilding the Spotlight index on your Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by rebuilding the Spotlight Index on your Mac.

> 1. Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Spotlight.
> 2. Click the Privacy tab.
> 3. Drag the folder or disk that you want to index again to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching. Or click the
>      Add (+) button and select the folder or disk to add.
>
>    To add an item to the Privacy tab, you must have ownership
>      permissions for that item. To learn about permissions, choose Help
>      from the Finder menu bar, then search for “permissions.”
> 4. From the same list of locations, select the folder or disk that you just added. Then click the Remove (–) button to remove it from the
>      list.
> 5. Quit System Preferences. Spotlight will reindex the contents of the folder or disk.

From: [How to rebuild the Spotlight index on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201716)

Comment: I have a hunch this might work. I'll report back when I get an opportunity in a few days to try it. Thanks for your help!